# JWT token issue in getStream analytic SDK

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

I m trying to use stream-analytics-ios and following the
[sdk use link](https://getstream.io/docs/)
doc says I need to add jwt token to info.plist file. 
But i believe jwt token is user specific not app specific. How can i add it to info.plist file if it is different for all user.

Answer (score 0):

Stream analytics API is available via both client-side token (containing user ID) and server-side token. iOS analytics client expects a server-side token. You could generate one programmatically or via websites like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) (you could take the example token from documentation and generate yours by using your secret key)

Token should contain the following payload

```
{
  "resource": "analytics",
  "action": "*",
  "feed_id": "*"
}
```

User is should be set via `setUserId:` method of Stream analytics client instance

```
StreamAnalytics *shared = [StreamAnalytics sharedInstance];
[shared setUserId:@"<your-user-id>"];
```